# Why I cannot pass parameters when running a pytest in pycharm?

Tags: pycharm, pytest

Here is the desription. I was learning the pytest and wroting some codes in pycharm. Below is my codes:

```
import pytest
import sys

# file name test_demo.py
class TestDemo1:  # start with Test
    def test_demo1(self):  # start with test
        print('testing1')

    def test_demo3(self):  # start with test
        print('testing3')
        assert 1 == 2

    def test_demo4(self):  # start with test
        print('testing4')

    def test_demo5(self):  # start with test
        print('testing5')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(pytest.main(['-vs', './testcases', '--reruns=2']))
```

When I run this program in pycharm, the interpreter is pytest. However, the result is

```
============================= test session starts =============================
collecting ... collected 4 items

test_demo1.py::TestDemo1::test_demo1 PASSED                              [ 25%]testing1

test_demo1.py::TestDemo1::test_demo3 FAILED                              [ 50%]testing3

test_demo1.py:9 (TestDemo1.test_demo3)
1 != 2

预期:2
实际:1
<点击以查看差异>

self = <test_demo1.TestDemo1 object at 0x0000020BC582C668>

    def test_demo3(self):  # start with test
        print('testing3')
>       assert 1 == 2
E       assert 1 == 2

test_demo1.py:12: AssertionError



test_demo1.py::TestDemo1::test_demo4 PASSED                              [ 75%]testing4

test_demo1.py::TestDemo1::test_demo5 PASSED                              [100%]testing5


========================= 1 failed, 3 passed in 0.06s =========================
```

Obviously, the program doesn't reruns twice. Same situation also occurs when I use other parameters, like '-n=2'. But, if I use another file whose name not includes 'test_' or '_test' which means the interpreter is python, then wrote codes in it as below:

```
import pytest

# file name all.py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    pytest.main(['test_demo1.py', '-n=2', '--reruns=4'])
```

the output becomes normal.
I've tried an alternative way to deal with that issue which is to edit the running configuration to input augments by hands. It works but fussy. Even thought I can handle this issue with these two ways, I wonder why I used a separate file to run the test will get a normal result, but abnormal in using test file itself?

Comment: I strongly suspect you use PyCharm's "pytest" run configuration and it starts and configures pytest itself, so your `if __name__ == '__main__'` code block is probably never executed. Try the `flaky` package which allows you to annotate individual tests as "flaky" so they get rerun no matter what pytest's global configuration is.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. You are totally right. The if __name__ == '__main__' code block is never executed. But I am confused about your first sentence. Why the 'pytest' run configuration configures pytest itself.

Comment: So that PyCharm can: run individual tests when you click on a green arrow next to it, get test results in a machine-readable format and display it in the IDE, and probably some other stuff.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I didn't express my question clearly. What I actually wonder is that why the if __name__ == '__main__' code block in the test_demo.py failed to execute.

Comment: Because PyCharm does not run the script, it runs PyTest directly, which imports your file as a module and then finds all tests inside it.